# Handling Async Await to use Firebase with react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

```
const userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

const checkRoomExists = async ()=>{
  var queryRef = firestore.collection("groups");
  try{
    console.log("userId: "+userID)
    var snapshot = await queryRef.where('participant', '==',userID).where('host','==',findParticipant).get()
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents1.');
      return;
    }
    else{
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      setChatroomAlready(doc.id)
    })}
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log('Error getting documents', e);
  }
  finally{
    console.log("chatroomAlready :"+chatroomAlready)
  }
}

async function performCreateGroup () {
  console.log("1 :"+findParticipant)
  checkRoomExists();
  console.log("2 :"+chatroomAlready)
}
//first call 
1: ZUxSZP09fzRzndr7vhK8wr56j3J3
2: (blank)
//second call returns what I expected exactly
1: ZUxSZP09fzRzndr7vhK8wr56j3J3
2: zQN4hbgqjKhHHHc70hPn
```

This is my code and variable chatroomAlready returns ''
But if I fast-refresh my app with react-native's function, It returns the expected value very well
I think this problem happens because my less understanding of async-await.
Any helps or clues can I solve this problem?

[image: this is my firebase]

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is.  What do you mean by "my variable chatroomAlready returns '' before I fast-refresh my app"?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I've fixed my question Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `userID` at the time of the query?  Log it just before you use it.  I think you'll be surprised about its value.  Please edit the question with your discoveries.

Comment: I've tested but userId's value was just I expected.
It returned real userId eventhough chatroomAlready returned nothing.

Comment: So, what do you expect the query to do that's different than what you expect?  We can't see the data in your database, so we don't know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I have made a function performCreateGroup.

Expected results and real result is on question's last part.

Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know - I can't see the data in your database to know if the query is returning the correct documents.  The problem here has nothing to do with async/await.  It has to do with the query and whether or not it returns the documents you want.

Comment: I have uploaded my capture of firebase storage

Answer (score 0):

i would rather use the following syntaxe:

```
queryRef.where('participant', '==',userID).where('host','==',findParticipant).get().then((snapshot)=>(
DO YOUR STUFF))
```

Since queryRef act as a promise.

Comment: `queryRef` does not "act as a promise".  It's a Query type object.  There is nothing wrong with the way the code is using async/await to deal with the promise returned by `get()`.  Changing it to use `then` will not affect the outcome.